# Difference between two time with time period am and pm

Tags: php, datetime

I have two times, like this:

```
$date1 = strtotime("02/12/2019 10:10:54 am");  
     $date2 = strtotime("02/12/2019 10:11:07 pm");
     $diff = abs($date2 - $date1); 
     $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24)); 
     $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) 
                           / (30*60*60*24));
     $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 -  
        $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24)); 
    $hours = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24  
   - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24) 
                               / (60*60));
    $minutes = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24  
     - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24  
                  - $hours*60*60)/ 60);
  $seconds = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24  
 - $months*30*60*60*24 - $days*60*60*24 
        - $hours*60*60 - $minutes*60));
  printf(" %d days, %d hours, "
 . "%d minutes, %d seconds", 
         $days, $hours, $minutes, $seconds);
```

I want to calculate the difference between them, but it's not working.

Comment: Use [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is much easier with the [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, which has a [`diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) method which produces a [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php) object that can output the difference in whatever format you like:

```
$date1 = new DateTime("02/12/2019 10:10:54 am"); 
$date2 = new DateTime("02/12/2019 10:11:07 pm");
$diff = $date1->diff($date2);
echo $diff->format('%y years, %m months, %d days, %h hours, %i minutes and %s seconds');
```

Output:

```
0 years, 0 months, 0 days, 12 hours, 0 minutes and 13 seconds
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/faShc)